# How to get string from dataPackageView.GetDataAsync()

Tags: c#, uwp, com-interop

I'm trying to get non-standard-format data from the clipboard using `DataPackageView.GetDataAsync`.  I am stumped on converting the returned `system.__ComObject` to a string.

**Here is the code:**

```
var dataPackageView = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();

if (dataPackageView.Contains("FileName"))
{
  var data = await dataPackageView.GetDataAsync("FileName");
  // How to convert data to string?

}
```

I am looking for a solution that will work with any non-standard clipboard format. "FileName" is an easily testable format as you can put it on the clipboard by copying a file in Windows Explorer.

In `C++/Win32`, I can get the clipboard data as follows:

```
OpenClipboard(nullptr);
UINT clipboarFormat = RegisterClipboardFormat(L"FileName");
HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(clipboarFormat);
char * pszText = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hData));
GlobalUnlock(hData);
CloseClipboard();
```

In `C++`, the clipboard data is just an array of bytes.  It must be possible to get the same array of bytes in C#, but I have no clue on unwrapping/converting the `system.__ComObject`

**Edit: Rephrasing the question:**

**How do I get a string or array of byes out of the system.__ComObject returned by dataPackageView.GetDataAsync(someFormat), where someFormat is an arbitrary clipboard format created by another application?**

It is very clear to me how to get the data.  The difficult part is using the data that is returned.

The accepted answer must show how to create a string or array of bytes from the "data" returned by

```
var data = await dataPackageView.GetDataAsync(someFormat);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article explains how custom dataPackage objects are implemented.

http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/dot-net/c-sharp/winrt-datapackage-custom-objects

The key is to cast the return value of dataPackageView.GetAsync() into an   **IRandomAccessStream**

Here is something that works:

```
var dataPackageView = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();

if (dataPackageView.Contains("FileName"))
{
  var data = await dataPackageView.GetDataAsync("FileName");
  // convert data to string
  var data = await dataPackageView.GetDataAsync("FileName");
  var dataObj = data as IRandomAccessStream;
  var stream = dataObj.GetInputStreamAt(0);
  IBuffer buff = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer((uint)dataObj.Size);
  await stream.ReadAsync(buff, (uint)dataObj.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
  var filePath = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff.ToArray());
  filePath = filePath.Replace("\0","");//get rid of null characters
}
```

This should work for any custom data format, not just "FileName".  If you do not require a string, you could just use the bytes available from the IRandomAccessStream.

Answer (score 3):

if you know its a file you can use the following code

```
var content = Clipboard.GetContent();

IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> files = await content.GetStorageItemsAsync();
var file = files.First() as StorageFile;
```

From [MSDN article on StandardDataFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.standarddataformats.aspx)

> The DataPackage class supports a number of legacy formats for interoperability between Windows Store apps and desktop apps. To retrieve these formats, you pass one of the following strings to the DataPackageView.GetDataAsync method instead of a value from the StandardDataFormats class.

eg

```
var content = Clipboard.GetContent();
var data = await content.GetDataAsync("PenData"); //Stream for HGLOBAL corresponding to CF_PENDATA
```

Comment: The data that I want to get is not necessarily a file.  As stated in the question, I am looking for a solution that will work with any non-standard clipboard format.

Comment: I know thats why I pointed you to the article containing supported formats

Comment: The MSDN article linked above does not provide any details about working with the data returned from dataPackageView.GetDataAsync. The code that I listed in the question already calls dataPackageView.GetDataAsync, as the article recommends.  The main point of my question is what to do with that data.  The returned data is a system.__ComObject, and I have no idea how to use it.